# Bluetooth not functioning in Lenovo y50-70

Tags: bluetooth

I am using Linux Mint 17.3 and eventhough the bluetooth icon appears and am able to toggle the bluetooth on/off still no device appears when scanning.

The output of commands:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp.  
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp.   
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub  
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 062a:0201 Creative Labs Defender Office Keyboard (K7310) S Zodiak KM-9010  
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. 4-Port HUB  
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:b728 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.   
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 5986:055e Acer, Inc   
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c069 Logitech, Inc. M500 Laser Mouse  
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1532:0201 Razer USA, Ltd   
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  

$usb-devices

T:  Bus=01 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=480 MxCh=14
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0002 Rev=03.19
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 3.19.0-32-generic xhci-hcd
S:  Product=xHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=0000:00:14.0
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  2 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1532 ProdID=0201 Rev=02.00
S:  Manufacturer=Razer
S:  Product=Razer Tartarus
C:  #Ifs= 3 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=usbhid
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=00 Prot=01 Driver=usbhid
I:  If#= 2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=00 Prot=02 Driver=usbhid

T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=01 Cnt=02 Dev#=  3 Spd=1.5 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS= 8 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=046d ProdID=c069 Rev=56.01
S:  Manufacturer=Logitech
S:  Product=USB Laser Mouse
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=98mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=01 Prot=02 Driver=usbhid

T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=05 Cnt=03 Dev#=  4 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=ef(misc ) Sub=02 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=5986 ProdID=055e Rev=36.51
S:  Manufacturer=Generic
S:  Product=Lenovo EasyCamera
S:  SerialNumber=200901010001
C:  #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=0e(video) Sub=01 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=0e(video) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo

T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=06 Cnt=04 Dev#=  5 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.10 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0bda ProdID=b728 Rev=02.00
S:  Manufacturer=Realtek 
S:  Product=Bluetooth Radio 
S:  SerialNumber=00e04c000001
C:  #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb

T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=08 Cnt=05 Dev#=  6 Spd=480 MxCh= 4
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1a40 ProdID=0101 Rev=01.11
S:  Product=USB 2.0 Hub
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=06 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  7 Spd=1.5 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 1.10 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS= 8 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=062a ProdID=0201 Rev=01.00
S:  Product=USB-compliant keyboard
C:  #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=usbhid
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=01 Prot=02 Driver=usbhid

T:  Bus=02 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=5000 MxCh= 4
D:  Ver= 3.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=03 MxPS= 9 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0003 Rev=03.19
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 3.19.0-32-generic xhci-hcd
S:  Product=xHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=0000:00:14.0
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

T:  Bus=03 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=480 MxCh= 2
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0002 Rev=03.19
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 3.19.0-32-generic ehci_hcd
S:  Product=EHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=0000:00:1a.0
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

T:  Bus=03 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  2 Spd=480 MxCh= 6
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=8087 ProdID=8008 Rev=00.05
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

T:  Bus=04 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=480 MxCh= 2
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0002 Rev=03.19
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 3.19.0-32-generic ehci_hcd
S:  Product=EHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=0000:00:1d.0
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

T:  Bus=04 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  2 Spd=480 MxCh= 8
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=8087 ProdID=8000 Rev=00.05
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub
```

I am not sure what is wrong with this, any help will be much appreciated.

Wi-Fi works by the way, if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for most Linux Mint kernels

```
sudo apt-get git build-essential linux-headers-generic
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
cd rtlwifi_new
make
sudo make install
cd ~
git clone -b troy https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723au_bt.git
cd rtl8723au_bt-troy
make
sudo make install
```

Reboot

Comment: Running the first make command give the error:
>make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-32-generic'
arch/x86/Makefile:129: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support
Makefile:669: Cannot use CONFIG_CC_STACKPROTECTOR_REGULAR: -fstack-protector not supported by compiler
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `Folder/rtlwifi_new'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-32-generic'
make: *** [all] Error 2
`

Comment: Run the first command again, it was missing a -

Comment: Am sorry the problem with the make was that i was working in a directory having space in the name (Untitled Folder). I confirm that the above answer resolved my problem after also changing to apt-get